# Add To Cart button, Product with custom options that are not required

Tags: custom-options, product-list, addtocart

I want to change the behavior of the Add to Cart button from the list / grid views. Where this is clicked for a product that has custom options that are required, the customer is taken into the product page to complete the options, and then they add to cart.

I want the same behavior for a product that has custom options that are not required. The add to cart button add the product into the shopping cart.

So my question is, how can I change Add to Cart button in list/grid views so that you are moved into the product page whether the optional are required or not.

I realize that making one or more of the options mandatory would solve this, but the options all need to be non-mandatory for reasons.

Answer (score 1):

In `.../template/catalog/product/list.phtml`, you'll see `$this->getAddToCartUrl($_product)`. This generates the URL to add to cart. You can create a custom function that places the product URL instead in your case. Check it out.

- Takes in `$_product` as its argument
- Checks if `$_product` has ***any*** custom options. See below
- Returns `$this->getAddToCartUrl(...)` if no custom options. Returns `$this->getProductUrl(...)` if at least one custom option is present.

To check if a product has any custom attributes at all..

```
$options = $product->getOptions();
if ($options) {
    return true; // has custom options
} else {
    return false; // no custom options
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop in list.phtml which displays addtocart button,

check if product has $_product()->getoptions() then change the hide your add to cart button and add another button and add redirection url to this button to redirect to product detail page.